# Text() doesn't expand vertically to fit multiline text

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have this in a View:

```
List {
GeometryReader { geo in
                        Text("\(name)")
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            .lineLimit(nil)
                            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: .infinity)
                            .font(.system(size: 26))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            
                            //.font(.title)
                            //.multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
}
```

How can I make all text visible while maintaining font size?

[image: multiline text clipped vertically]

Comment: I don't know about swift but, you appear to be setting a fixed height and the element must have `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: The problem that you are facing is that `GeometryReader` wrapping `Text` so that `List` cannot know the actual height of `Text`. It should be fine when getting rid of `GeometryReader`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the List in the Geometryreader and update width to .infinity

```
GeometryReader { geo in
                    List {
                        Text("name")
                            .font(.system(size: 28))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .frame(width:.infinity, height: .infinity)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    }
                }
```

now with this code your text should be expanded vertically